# Original literature on adversary argument

Tags: reference-request, lower-bounds

I want to know about the early invention/use of the adversary argument (see the [lecture note by Jeff Erickson](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/29-adversary.pdf)) which is a technique for establishing lower bounds of problems.

I cannot find the original papers which invented/advocated adversary argument or the first problems whose lower bounds are obtained by adversary argument. (In particular, I am quite surprised that there are no wiki pages on adversary argument.)

Do you know some original literature on adversary argument?

Comment: Huh. This is not exclusive to lower bounds, so maybe it comes from a whole different area?

Answer (score 1):

The oldest literature can be traced back to Andrew Yao's min-max [principle](http://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/dectreechap.pdf), which inturns has its elder root from [von Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_theorem)'s.

History of game theory is not continuous in time. At least, there was some rise and then fall in the intensity of mathematicians' attention to this theory.